# OleDbConnection: How to open and close a connection using a function

Tags: c#, database-connection, oledb, oledbconnection

I have a function that connects to a Excel File:

```
    public OleDbConnection connection;

    public void eConnection(string srcString, string id)
    {
        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + srcString + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
        connection.Open();

    }
```

I want to create another function that will close this existing connection when called or invoke

This is what I have to try and close the existing connection:

```
    public void eCloseConnection()
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
```

How can I close the existing connection using a function that calls the same connection and closes it

How can I test to see if the connection is closed?

Comment: Does that mean you have more than on connection string?  The code you have only has one connection and will only close the latest connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it like this. [`OleDbConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=netframework-4.7.1) implements the [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.1) interface should be disposed as soon as you are done using it, and the best way to do it is to use it as a local variable declared in a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement:

```
public void DoStuffWithExcel(string srcString)
{
    conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + srcString + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
    using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        // do your stuff here...
    }
}
```

The `using` statement ensures the connection will be disposed properly even if an exception occurs inside the `using` block.
This way is the best way to prevent memory leaks, as well as to use the connection pool.

From Microsoft docs page [OLE DB, ODBC, and Oracle Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ole-db-odbc-and-oracle-connection-pooling):

> We recommend that you always close or dispose of a connection when you are finished using it in order to return the connection to the pool. Connections that are not explicitly closed may not get returned to the pool. For example, a connection that has gone out of scope but that has not been explicitly closed will only be returned to the connection pool if the maximum pool size has been reached and the connection is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep a global object for a connection hidden inside a class. This adds more problems than the one solved. You should keep track how many time that code is called and how many connection it creates. And of course this makes a lot more complicated the closing part.

Instead the C# language offers a better approach to this kind of problem. An approach particularly suited for objects like a connection that requires unmanaged resources to be realeased to the OS as soon as possible.

You should instead use this approach both if you want to have a class that handles your connections or if you just want to open and use a connection

```
public static class DbUtility
{
    public static OleDbConnection eConnection(string srcString)
    {
        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + srcString + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    } 
    .... other static utilities
}
```

Now you can use your class in this way

```
string srcFile = @"d:\temp\myFile.xlsx";
using(OleDbConnection cn = DbUtility.eConnection(srcFile))
{
     .. use your connection

} // <- at this point your connection is automatically closed and disposed.
```

The [using keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is of great help when you need to just destroy your disposable objects like a connection. In this way you don't keep a global object around when you don't need it.